# Simulate numpy vectorized function on a meshgrid

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

This is the example given on how to use `numpy.meshgrid`

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)
```

What if I have a `meshgrid` like `xx`,`yy` above, but my function is a regular function that isn't `vectorized`, `f(x,y)`, for example, the regular `math.sin` function ?

I know I can loop through the `list of lists` of `xx`,`yy`, but I want to try to simulate `vectorized` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care the speed, you can use `numpy.vectorize()`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)
z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)

import math
def f(x, y):
    return math.sin(x**2 + y**2) / (x**2 + y**2)

np.allclose(np.vectorize(f)(xx, yy), z)
```